# How to show stability for this discretization?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, finite-difference-methods

I am studying the 1D wave equation:
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial t^2} - a^2 \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} = 0
$$

And solving it numerically with this implicit finite differences discretization:

$$
\frac{u^{n+1}_{j}-2u^{n}_{j}+u^{n-1}_{j}}{{\Delta}t^2} - \frac{a^2}{4h^2}( (u^{n+1}_{j+1}-2u^{n+1}_{j}+u^{n+1}_{j-1})+2(u^{n}_{j+1}-2u^{n}_{j}+u^{n}_{j-1})+(u^{n-1}_{j+1}-2u^{n-1}_{j}+u^{n-1}_{j-1}))=0
$$

I'd like to show that this method is stable. I've tried to use the Von Neumman method as applied [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/372969/finite-difference-implicit-schema-for-wave-equation-1d-not-unconditionally-stabl) but the algebraic manipulations get way too tricky. After getting to a 2nd degree equation like in the link, I am not able to simplify it and show that $|G| < 1$, and thus the method is uncondinally stable. Is there a simpler way to do this. Any pointer to a nice reference on this are very welcome.

Comment: @Merkh Actually this is a common discretization. Averaging the 3 point stencils for $u_{xx}$ over time makes it unconditionally stable. Note it is an implicit scheme.

Comment: @user3158384 It would be useful if you write out what you have and where you are stuck. The von Neumann analysis should work fine.

Comment: I am also reasonably certain this is worked out in Strauss's book (or perhaps it is an exercise).

Comment: Thank you @Jeff, I'll check out your reference.

Comment: See problem 3 here: http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~jwcalder/5587F16/hw10_sol.pdf It's a very similar scheme.

Comment: Hi @user , you may read *introduction to Partial Differential Equations : A Computational Approach* book by Ragnar Winther and Aslak Tveito. I have read it before, with also the same question as yours in mind, with the same equation also. If I am not forgotten, it uses finite-difference in matrix form and a quadratic equation in terms of the square matrix. The Discriminant of the equation must be nonnegative, then it will result the stability condition. But you may check this yourself.